# How would I go about renaming a column name in pandas, in the same line that I made a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm only allowed 4 lines of code to complete 6 objectives.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name', 'Year 1','Year 2'])
df = df.rename(columns = {'Name':'Project', 'Year 1)':'y23','Year 2':'y24'})
df.to_csv('data/df.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('data/df.csv')
print(df2)
```

I've got to get this down to 4 lines, whilst also indexing a column. Basically, create a df, with the first 3 columns, then append the 3 columns. Then save it as a csv, and then read it with an index column and then print it.

Update:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name', 'Year 1','Year 2']).rename(columns = {'Name':'Project', 'Year 1)':'y23','Year 
    2':'y24'}).to_csv('data/df.csv')        
df2 = pd.read_csv('data/df.csv')                                                      
print(df2) 

                                                             Solved
```

Comment: a few of the '.' functions can be added onto the end of the last line

Comment: also you haven't appended any columns, only (attempted to) rename the original column names

Comment: so df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name', 'Year 1','Year 2']).rename()?

Comment: Yep, that should work. Or put the .csv on the end of the line before (remove df = )

Comment: out of curiosity, who set such a requirement on the number of lines?)

Comment: I would assume it's a homework question, hence the vague answering

Comment: Quizzing our knowledge of the subject in question, but evidently I never thought that rename would work on the end of a line like that, idk why

Comment: How would I introduce an index into this?

Comment: Dataframes have an index by default,  `df.index.values` will show you what it is but it should show up in your csv as the first column

Comment: Yes, but they're asking me to set the name of the index

Comment: set the name of the index, or set the name column as the index?

Comment: Exact question is: Load the saved file into a new dataframe called df2 with the index set to ID

Comment: is ID the same as name? there is a set_index() function in pandas

Comment: I just read your actual answer properly. If I add .to_csv to the first line as well as .rename, then I'll have a line free to introduce the index, no?

Comment: there is a index name (if you google change index name pandas, you'll find it), but I've never seen it used, it doesn't feel like what the question is after but I'm not sure

Comment: No, it's exactly what I needed.

Comment: df = pd.DataFrame(old_df, columns = [' Name', 'year 1','year 2']).rename(columns = {'Name':'Project', 'year 1':'y23','year 2':'y24'}).to_csv('data/df.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('data/df.csv')
df2 = budget_df.set_index('ID')
df2

Comment: old_df includes the ID column that I can then set as the index

Comment: @EmiOB I could use some more help, as some syntax confuses me here and there throughout all of this, if you'd be so kind.

Comment: sorry, was night.  Do you still need help? I suggest updating your question if so :)

Comment: ahh no thats alright. I've sorted most of it, now I'm just battling with regex

Answer (score 0):

a few of your '.' functions can be joined onto the previous line, for example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.function()
```

can be written as:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data).function()
```

other than some exceptions including for the to_csv or to_excel, where:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('file.csv')
```

can be written as:

```
pd.DataFrame(data).to_csv('file.csv')
```

(Answer deliberately vague as homework question).